# Is there something like "spoiler neutral language"?

Tags: plot-explanation

I sometimes read summaries of episodes I've already watched, but for shows where I'm not yet at the latest episode, and read things like "Person X is *presumably* killed".

Now I immediately feel spoilered, knowing they're still alive and will reappear at some later point.

I understand we can't write "Person X is killed", because that just wouldn't be true.

But is there a way to phrase those things differently, so that it's both true and non-spoilering? And if there's not yet, can we create something like that?

I could only think of the phrase "spoiler neutral language" to describe that, and haven't found anything via Google.

Side note: I'd love to have created the tag 'spoilers' for this question, but don't have the reputation to do so.

Comment: Frankly this is off-topic for this site. It's *asking* for something to be done and that's not what we do. Of course it would be possible to write summaries in a non-spoiler fashion but a summary is, by default, spoilery if you haven't seen the episode. What exactly should they leave out not spoil *something*?

Comment: To clarify: I read summaries for episodes I have already watched (e.g., where a person gets "presumably" killed). I'm just not up to date with the show, and at a later episode (which I haven't yet watched), it will turn out the person wasn't killed.

Comment: How do you know that the summary is written with the knowledge of future episodes? Just because the word "presumably" is used doesn't mean the person *isn't* dead just that (IDK) they *might* be dead. Writers love to subvert expectations and resurrect "dead" characters all the time. Regardless, the question is still off-topic.

Comment: Side note a "spoiler" tag would be what we call a "meta tag" and those aren't encouraged as they are tags that don't say anything by themselves - you can't tell what the question is about unless they're paired with some other tag

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about movies or TV, within the scope defined in the [help/on-topic].